# Regex value is converted into an empty object after sending it in the request body. Why is it happening and what are the other ways to solve this?

Tags: node.js, regex, api, object, axios

I am using Node.js and I need to pass the following filter object in the request body:

```
const filter = {
  'userName': { '$regex': /^Test$/i },
  'userCode': '0071'
}
```

I used axios to call *userMicroservice* API and added the filter I created in the request body:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
      `${userMicroservice()}/find`,
      {
        query: filter,
      }
    );
```

In *userMicroservice*, when I console.log() the request body, I got the below output. '$regex': is now an empty object.

```
query: { 
    'userName':{ '$regex': {} },
    'userCode': '0071'
}
```

Why is it giving out an empty object instead of a regex and what are the other ways to pass a regex object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you are passing `/^Test$/i`, which is a JavaScript regex literal.  JSON APIs are meant for passing around text.  So, one option would be to just pass the regex as text:

```
const filter = {
  'userName': { '$regex': "^Test$" },
  'userCode': '0071'
}
```

Then, when you have received the text regex, create a new `RegExp` object in your JavaScript code, e.g.

```js
var regexString = "^Test$";
var regexp = new RegExp(regexString);
if (regexp.test("Test")) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: very useful in mongodb dynamic queries, thanks!